# Failed to execute goal io.swagger:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:2.2.3:generate (default) on project Code generation failed

Tags: mongodb, swagger, pom.xml

I am getting below error when trying

```
[INFO] reading from C:/Project/xxxmongo-rest/src/main/resources/spec/api-docs.json
[INFO] reading from C:/Project/xxxmongo-rest/src/main/resources/spec/api-docs.json
[WARNING] Output directory does not exist, or is inaccessible. No file (.swager-codegen-ignore) will be evaluated.
[ERROR]
java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config!
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate (DefaultGenerator.java:685)
    at io.swagger.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <client.package.key>bs.mongo</client.package.key> 
    <!--<client.spec.gen>http://localhost:8081/xxx/v2/api-docs</client.spec.gen>-->
    <swagger.spec.gen.skip>true</swagger.spec.gen.skip>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!--crud base controllers-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xx-api-crud</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xx.xx</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootcamp-mongo-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xx.xx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xx-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.XX.MongoRestApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I have this exact issue... @paa have you found any solution so far?